# how to find a word in ASCII file using python

Tags: indexing, find, ascii, python-2.5

I want to find a word and its index but the problem is I am only getting its first position while the word appear more than one time in file. The file's content is,

**[MAKE DATA:STUDENT1=AENIE:AGE14,STUDENT2=JOHN:AGE15,STUDENT3=KELLY:AGE14,STUDENT4=JACK:AGE16,STUDENT5=SNOW:AGE16;SET RECORD:STUDENT1=GOOD,STUDENT2=,STUDENT3=BAD,STTUDENT4=,STUDENT5=GOOD]**

following is my code,

```
    import sys,os,csv
    x = str(raw_input("Enter file name :")) + '.ASCII'
    fp = open(x,'r')
    data = fp.read()
    fp.close()
    found = data.find("STUDENT1")
    print found
```

here the word "STUDENT1" appear two time while my code gives its only 1st index position. I want its second index position too. Similarly a word may appear several times in file so how can I find its all index position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the optional start parameter to [`str.find()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) to search the string again starting after the previous match:

```
found = data.find("STUDENT1")
while found != -1:
    print found
    found = data.find("STUDENT1", found+1)
```

It would be slightly more efficient (but less concise) to use `found+len("STUDENT1")` instead of `found+1`.

Alternatively you could use the [`re.finditer()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
import re
for match in re.finditer("STUDENT1", data):
    print match.start()
```

Comment: No problem, if my answer helped click the outline of the check mark next to my answer to accept it as the solution.